# How to change curve type?

Tags: bezier-curves, path

I've created a bezier curve but now I want to change its type to path. 
How to achieve this?
And btw. if I can animate both: bezier curve and path, what is the practical difference between those?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, so there are two main kinds of curves in Blender. [Bézier and NURBS](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/curves/structure.html). A path is a NURBS curve and you want to convert a bezier curve to it. To do this is really easy:

1. Click on the bezier curve in question.
2. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. Select the bezier curve by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>
4. Press <kbd>Space</kbd> and search for ["Set Spline Type"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/curves/editing/introduction.html#set-spline-type)
5. Click "NURBS"

Now you have a "path" or NURBS curve to work with. I found this solution in reverse on [here](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?351643-How-to-convert-a-NURBS-Curve-to-BEZIER-in-2-7).

As for the practical difference between the two, as far as i can tell, the NURBS curve is more accurate and precise than its bezier counterpart. I hope this helps.