# Copy Path from Bezier Curve

Tags: bezier-curves, path, duplicate

I have a Bezier curve and want to create a path that has the same curve/shape as the bezier curve. It is offset on z-axis from the bezier curve. How do I do that?

Comment: I followed this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42228/how-to-change-curve-type?rq=1 In geometry nodes, just added set spline type and set it to nurbs.